# Proper syntax for a CLI in bash that will accept arguments with spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

```
while getopts abp: optchar; do
    case "${optchar}" in

    a) # an option
        export OPTION_A=1
        ;;

    b) # Yet another option
        export b=1
        ;;

    p) # An option to supply player names to the function
        IFS=',' read -r -a PLAYER_NAMES <<<"${OPTARG}"
        ;;
    esac
done

for name in "${PLAYER_NAMES[@]}"; do
    echo ${name}
```

Now if you supply the 'players' keyword argument with a comma separated list, the function will ignore arguments that are separated by a space. For example if you run:

```
bash testexp.sh -p sherman,wilson, taylor
```

You will get

```
sherman
wilson
```

But taylor will not be included because his name wasn't added to the array variable.

How do you make the cli parser ignore the extra space, so that output is as follows?

```
sherman
wilson
taylor
```

Comment: That's how bash works: spaces separate words. If you need the space to be part of the word, you must use quotes, or escape the space with a backslash.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I'd recommend adding a proper shebang line (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, note that it must be the first line in the script), making the script executable (`chmod +x testexp.sh`), and then running it directly without the `bash` command (`./testexp.sh -p ...`).

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use apostrophes:

```
bash testexp.sh -p 'sherman,wilson, taylor'
```

Comment: Double-quotes would work as well. You could also escape the space:  `bash testexp.sh -p sherman,wilson,\ taylor`